# How do you use windows GDI methods in .NET that aren't in GDI+?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, gdi, kerning

I want to call a GDI method that I can't find in GDI+ in a .NET app.

In particular [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which gets kerning pairs for a specified font. I want to implement kerning (letter-spacing) on HTML5 canvas which isn't currently supported and I figured the best way was to pull out kerning pairs on my server and return a kerning table to the client.

How do you use windows library functions like this from .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find this method in `Windows API` for calling this method :

- 1 : add `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace to your project
- 2 : add the `API` class to your project and let it use `GetKerningPairs` method
  please remember that this function uses a struct called `KERNINGPAIR` we need to make sure it's defined in our class otherwise we'll get compile error !

  ```
  class API
  {
      [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
      static extern uint GetKerningPairs(IntPtr hdc, uint nNumPairs,
      [Out] KERNINGPAIR[] lpkrnpair);

      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
      struct KERNINGPAIR
      {
          public ushort wFirst; // might be better off defined as char
          public ushort wSecond; // might be better off defined as char
          public int iKernAmount;

          public KERNINGPAIR(ushort wFirst, ushort wSecond, int iKernAmount)
          {
              this.wFirst = wFirst;
              this.wSecond = wSecond;
              this.iKernAmount = iKernAmount;
          }

          public override string ToString()
          {
              return (String.Format("{{First={0}, Second={1}, Amount={2}}}", wFirst, wSecond, iKernAmount));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

now you can call this method through `API` class

Comment: Great stuff, thanks a lot! I will try this out, and see if the kerning pairs that come back are accurate or not. Have you got any experience of using this method?

Comment: you're welcome , I'm afraid not but if provided inputs are in the correct format you shouldn't be worried about this , and by the way http://www.pinvoke.net/ is a very useful website for `winAPI`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're out of luck.

According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2ea4ea08-835c-42ed-bd1e-aceb7b79beb4)

> It seems there’s no relevant classes for kerning pair. Glyphs will generate sensible default values for glyph indices and advance widths.

It may be possible to try [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.getkerningpairs) but as the note under that post says

> Please note: it appears that the data returned is for the default unicode block only.
>
> There may be a way to get more info by changing the code page ( strictly a guess on my part ).
>
> The only way I've been able to get ALL the kerning data is to parse the files directly; not easy to say the least.

Comment: That question is specifically asking whether it is possible to get the kerning pairs through .NET, no mention is made of the method that I linked to in the question. The other answer @Mehran displays a way of calling that method, have you ever tried calling that GDI method? It seems like it may be just what I need.

Comment: @dormisher - yes, the second link I posted (pinvoke) is exactly what Mehran suggests, and the caveat is that you can only get data for the default Unicode block. If that's ok for then you're sorted.

Comment: Ah I see, what exactly do you mean by "you can only get data for the default Unicode block".

Comment: @dormisher - I was quoting from the pinvoke site, but I assume it means the block of Unicode corresponding to your current region/language/locale settings in Windows.

Comment: Ah ok well that's good enough for me I think. Thank's for your help.